# Align items differently on different row and column on flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve as shown in the image using html css
[image]
I am trying to use flexbox and I have successfully placed the image as desired but can't align text as shown in above image what I have tried till so far is on below code

```css
* {

  margin: 0;

  padding: 0;

}

 ul, li{

list-style-type: none;

list-style: none;

  

}

li{

border: 2px solid green;

display: flex;

height: 200px;



}

li span{

   display: flex;

  align-items: center;



}

h4{

color: #059E9A;

}

a{

float: right;

text-decoration: none;

cursor: none;

color: black;

}

li a:before{

font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';

   content: "\f101";

   font-weight: 900; 

   float: left;

   margin-right: 0.4rem;

  

}

li a:after {

content: attr(time);

float: right;

color: #aeae9f;

font-size: 0.75rem;

font-style: italic;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"

  />

  <title>Page title</title>

</head>

<body>

   <ul>

           <li>

   <img src="https://avt.mkklcdnv6temp.com/23/q/23-1612849460.jpg" alt="">

   <h4>It feels so wrong to bite people</h4>

   <span>

 <a href="" time="2 hours ago">CHAPTER 93</a>

 <p></p>

   </span>

   <span>

 <a href="" time="2 hours ago">CHAPTER 92</a>

 <p></p>

   </span>

   <span>

 <a href="" time="1 day ago">CHAPTER 91</a>

 <p></p>

   </span>

 </li>

 <li>

   <img src="https://avt.mkklcdnv6temp.com/5/d/23-1610420366.jpg" alt="">

   <h4>Rebirth Of The Earth Immortal Venerable</h4>

   <span>

 <a href="" time="3 hours ago">CHAPTER 164</a>

 <p></p>

   </span>

   <span>

 <a href="" time="7 days ago">CHAPTER 163</a>

 <p></p>

   </span>

   <span>

 <a href="" time="15 days ago">CHAPTER 162</a>

 <p></p>

   </span>

 </li>

       </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is create two containers, one for the image and one for the text.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="https://avt.mkklcdnv6temp.com/23/q/23-1612849460.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="text-container">
            <h4>It feels so wrong to bite people</h4>
            <span>
                <a href="" time="2 hours ago">CHAPTER 93</a>
                <p></p>
            </span>
            <span>
                <a href="" time="2 hours ago">CHAPTER 92</a>
                <p></p>
            </span>
            <span>
                <a href="" time="1 day ago">CHAPTER 91</a>
                <p></p>
            </span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li {
    display: flex;
}

.text-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
li {
        display: flex;
    }

    .text-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
    
    span {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>
            <img src="https://avt.mkklcdnv6temp.com/23/q/23-1612849460.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="text-container">
                <h4>It feels so wrong to bite people</h4>
                <span>
                    <a href="" time="2 hours ago">CHAPTER 93</a>
                    <p>22.00</p>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <a href="" time="2 hours ago">CHAPTER 92</a>
                    <p>22.00</p>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <a href="" time="1 day ago">CHAPTER 91</a>
                    <p>22.00</p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks mate I have been thinking trying this method too

Comment: You're welcome. Try to sketch the way you want your layout (e.g. draw the containers). This will help you understand how to create your containers using flexboxes